# Scoped style affecting other pages

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two pages in my nuxt app and both pages should have different backgrounds. However one background is overriding the other

index.vue

```
<style scoped>
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#banner {
  background-image: url("~assets/img/newbg.png");
}
</style>
```

login.vue

```
<style >


body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
    ),
    url("~assets/img/starter_image.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

The background of the login.vue overrides the index.vue. if a scope the style of login.vue the styling of the page changes.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely override the styles because you're not using scoped attribute which will allow it to override the styles of the parent component.

If you want to have another background in Login.vue

then this might help:

Inside Login.vue

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper" v-bind:style="bgc">
    *Write your html here*
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #111;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    data: {
        bgc: {
            backgroundColor: ''
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
index.vue

    <style scoped>
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #banner {
      background-image: url("~assets/img/newbg.png");
    }
    </style>
```

```html
  login.vue

    <style scoped>

    body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(
          to right,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
        ),
        url("~assets/img/starter_image.jpg");
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }
    </style>
```

you can use scoped for your component that will not affect to your other component.there are two different components (login, index).